# Can we use SQL Server 2016 CTP3 for production environment?

Tags: sql-server

As I have the plan for upgrading my SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2016. It is good to go with preview releases for production? Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Why would you want to use in production a *CTP* edition that is three versions behind the current *Release Candidate (RC2)*? Have you checked the relevant product pages lately? The official pages also cover whether RC2 has a go-live license or not

Comment: Please note that `CTP` & `RC` versions a bit unstable. So maybe the best way - wait RTM release? :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for you valuable replay. Just have confusion with going to production with Pre releases. I will check in production page.

Comment: @Devart Thanks will wait for RTM release. : )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With Microsoft [CTP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2010/06/14/what-is-a-community-technology-preview-ctp/) means

> grouping the features into multiple “sets” that have a correct logical sequence as well as balance the effort across all the component teams to finish the “set” around the same time

Basically this means that each CTP adds on features to the last one till the final release.

Each CTP is tested, and as bug-free as possible unless the release notes mention an issue.

Each CTP is feature complete as per the original CTP definition.

In this light, I would say that if you need a feature badly which is available in the CTP, you should evaluate using the CTP even in production.

Even all microsoft products' RTM have had major issues, and have needed (sometimes multiple) patches/SP to fix them.